# Why is my second DAG sending sigterm signal and failing after being triggered by the first DAG upon completion?

Tags: apache-kafka, airflow

I have a DAG that generates json and sends to kafka topic. Upon completion of this, it will trigger my second dag wherein the second dag consumes the data, aggregates it and sends the aggregated data to another kafka topic. but when the first dag triggers the second dag, it starts exexuting, connects to kafka host, checks the topic and sends the SIGTERM signal and closes.

I am giving my second dag code here.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer

from kafka.consumer.group import KafkaConsumer

import json

default_args = {

    'owner': 'airflow',

    'depends_on_past': False,

    'start_date': datetime(2023, 6, 16),

    'retries': 0,

    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),

}




dag = DAG(

    'data_processor_dag',

    default_args=default_args,

    schedule_interval='@once')





def process_data():

    

    # Create a Kafka consumer object

    consumer = KafkaConsumer('checkdata', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')




    # Create a Kafka producer object for the processed data

    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')


# Process each message in the Kafka topic  



    for message in consumer:

        data = json.loads(message.value.decode('utf-8'))




        # Access the messageData array

        message_data = data['event']['messageData']

        timestamp1 = data['timestamp']

        nanos = data['nanos']

        vin = data['vin']




        # Calculate the average rating for all messages

        Safetyratings = [message['SafetyRating'] for message in message_data]

        PerformanceRatings = [message['PerformanceRating'] for message in message_data]

        EfficiencyRatings = [message['EfficiencyRating'] for message in message_data]

        distance = [message['distance_travelled'] for message in message_data]

        actual_distance = round(sum(distance), 0)

        avg_safetyrating = round(sum(Safetyratings) / len(Safetyratings), 0)

        avg_performancerating = round(sum(PerformanceRatings) / len(PerformanceRatings), 0)

        avg_efficiencyrating = round(sum(EfficiencyRatings) / len(EfficiencyRatings), 0)

        Score = round(((avg_efficiencyrating + avg_performancerating + avg_safetyrating)/3), 0)




        # Create a new JSON object with the aggregated data

        aggregated_json = {

                    "SafetyRating": avg_safetyrating,

                    "PerformanceRating": avg_performancerating,

                    "EfficiencyRating": avg_efficiencyrating,

                    "Distance_travelled": actual_distance,

                    "Score": Score,

                    "vin": vin,

                    "timestamp": timestamp1,

                    "nanos": nanos

        }




producer.send('aggregated_data', json.dumps(aggregated_json).encode('utf-8'))




    # Close the Kafka consumer and producer

    consumer.close()

    producer.close()




    print("Data processing complete")




process_data_task = PythonOperator(

    task_id='process_data',

    python_callable=process_data,

    dag=dag,

)

process_data
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to create dependencies between DAGs or tasks using Airflow, but using an asynchronous call is not a nice way to achieve your goal.
You can use [a basic task dependency](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/tasks.html) between your tasks, you can create a DAG for each task, and create another DAG which uses a [task sensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task/index.html#airflow.sensors.external_task.ExternalTaskSensor) and wait first the first DAG completion.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. My first DAG is working fine. It succeeds and then triggers this DAG. this DAG starts executing and sends the Winch signal or SIGTERM. I couldn't resolve that issue. I have used the trigger dan run operator in the first DAG.